# Random SQL Errors After Running Large Process

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a ASP.NET application which includes a month end process which needs executed at the start of each month to generate payment records etc. for clients. There are a large (200-300) number of SQL queries being executed but not simultaneously and connections are closed after each is ran.

Since moving from a Server with SQL Server 2008 Enterprise to one with SQL Server 2008 Express I've noticed that when running this process use of the rest of the system is not possible and the system starts generating random errors such as String was not recognized as a valid Boolean (when the value is correct) or  System.IndexOutOfRangeException (for fields that are returned).

These errors only occur after the process is started and remain for about 15 - 20 mins after completion when they go away. None of these errors occurred on the old server/SQL Server version. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

SQL express has limited usage of cpu and memory.
Please check this [SQL Server 2008 Express or Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549088/sql-server-2008-express-or-enterprise) as well.

If it is a production database, I would highly recommend you to switch back to enterprise version.